# Why does this pointer get assigned while copying a linked list?

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

In this code:

```
Node *CopyList(Node **head) {
    Node *current = *head;
    Node *NewNode = NULL;
    Node *tail = NULL;

    while (current != NULL ) {
        if (NewNode == NULL) {
            NewNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            NewNode->data = current->data;
            NewNode->next = NULL; // routine
            tail = NewNode;
        } else {
            tail->next = malloc(sizeof(Node)); // here 
            tail = tail->next;
            tail->data = current->data;
            tail->next = NULL;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return(NewNode);
}
```

Why are we assigning `tail->next` to the result of a `malloc()` call? Evidently, if we don't do so a segmentation fault occurs.

Why didn't we just allocate `tail` instead of `tail->next`? What are some situations in which I should allocate next like this?

Comment: This code seems reasonable.  On the first iteration, it allocates the head of the new list (`NewNode`), and on each subsequent iteration, it extends the tail of the new list.  What did you think was wrong with this?  There shouldn't be a segfault due to `tail` because it won't be NULL when used.  The only thing wrong here is that the return value of `malloc` is not checked for NULL.

Comment: I didn't think that wrong just I didn't get it the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a convenience, to avoid an extra variable:

```
Node* temp = malloc(sizeof(Node)); // here 
temp->data = current->data ;
temp->next = NULL ;

tail->next = temp ;
tail = tail->next;
```

*Why we didn't just allocate tail instead tail->next ?*

Tail is already allocated, it is acting as the previous node, so we can link it to the next one. We allocate a new node and link tail to that node with tail->next = that_node.

Answer (score 1):

here NewNode represents New Linked list head. So for the first time in while loop it gets allocated so it's not getting changed next time onward. Coming to your question that 'tail->next' instead of 'tail' because for the first time when 'NewNode == NULL' then 'tail = NewNode' gets executed means tail is having NewNode address. So next onward you need to copy next block into 'tail->next' as tail is already having 'NewNode'.

Comment: I'm sorry but there is something I still don't get it, what do you mean by I need copy next block into 'tail->next' could you explain more spesific please?

Comment: with in first if 'tail=NewNode' means NewNode is assigned to tail. Now in else part you should copy next block to tail means you need to allocate new block to 'tail->next' as tail is already having NewNode. Once you try dry run by taking linked list having more than 2 nodes. Then you get it easily